# How much data versus dimensions are needed to overcome the curse of dimensionality?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

Are there any guidelines for knowing how many training samples are needed based on the number of features you have in order to not have accuracy degradation as a result of the curse of dimensionality? As in are there any rules of thumb for ballpark estimates of appropriate dataset sizes verses dimensions or are there methods for determining it on a case-by-case basis? Feel free to link to papers or things of that nature if relevant.